# converting table with certain column names to one having those column names as row values using sql

Tags: sql

I want to convert a table that looks like this

| id | column_a | column_b | column_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 345 | 456 |
| 2 | 789 | 678 | 567 |

to something that looks like this (using SQL)

| id | column_type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | column_a | 123 |
| 2 | column_a | 789 |
| 1 | column_b | 345 |
| 2 | column_b | 678 |
| 1 | column_c | 456 |
| 2 | column_c | 567 |

Is it possible to get a table converted like this using SQL?
Although I tried using Union all and was able to get the amount and id column but I am unable to figure out how the 2nd column(column_type) can be achieved.
The query that I had used is as below:

```
SELECT id, column_a as amount from table
Union all 
SELECT id, column_b as amount from table
Union all
SELECT id, column_c as amount from table
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear, I will try rephrasing it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `SELECT id, 'column_a' as column_type, column_a as amount from table etc`.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @jarlh Perfect! Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it into the `union all`:

```
SELECT id, 'column_a' as type, column_a as amount from table
Union all 
SELECT id, 'column_a' as type, column_b as amount from table
Union all
SELECT id, 'column_a' as type, column_c as amount from table;
```

If your database supports lateral joins, I would recommend using those to unpivot the data.  If the "table" is large or really a view or complex query, there are alternative methods that have better performance than the above.

Comment: Although I didn't mention this in my question but can we unpivot the data in AWS Athena? I tried doing it and am getting the following error : SQL Error [100071] [HY000]: [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. line 8:3: mismatched input 'for' expecting {',', ')'}

Comment: @jacee . . . This is standard SQL and should work in any database.  The string "for" does not appear in this answer, so I do not know why your version is not working.  You might want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use UNPIVOT as below:

```
select id,
  column_type,
  amount
from tablename2
unpivot
(
  amount
  for column_type in (column_a, column_b, column_c)
) unpiv;
```

**Output:**

```
id  column_type amount
1   column_a    123
1   column_b    345
1   column_c    456
2   column_a    789
2   column_b    678
2   column_c    567
```